# MySQL combining two strings result in 0

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table, for instance `items`. When I try to update the table with the following query:

```
UPDATE items
SET link = link + some_value;
```

the result value for every link will be `0`, instead of the concatenated string.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `CONCAT` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding 2 strings. Since a string is not a number, both will be seen as `0`, and therefore, `0 + 0` will result in `0`.

To do this you can use MySQL's [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
UPDATE items
SET link = CONCAT(link, 'some_value');
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess link is a character field, so you should use `CONCAT`.

```
UPDATE items
SET link = concat( link, 'some_value');
```